# Magento 1.9 edit CartController redirect when on mobile

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I want to edit the Magento 1.9.4 CartController.php file, to change the redirect when a user is on a mobile device (max screen width 750px).

I set the default Magento add to cart redirect method to stay on the same page and not redirect to the cart. But when a user is on a mobile device, I want to redirect them direct to the cart.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check device resolution in .php file, so instead of resolution you can check mobile agent.

To do this add a helper function to check if mobile device is requesting in any of your custom module helper `app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/Helper/Data.php`

```
public function isMobile(){
    //return true;
    $regex_match = "/(nokia|iphone|ipad|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"
        . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"
        . "blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"
        . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"
        . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"
        . ")/i";

    //DISPLAY DESKTOP THEME ON HAUWEI TAB
    if(preg_match("/(huaweimediapad)/i", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
        return false;
    }

    if (preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android") && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"mobile")){

        return true;

    }

    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android")){

        return false;

    }



    $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
    $mobile_agents = array(
        'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
        'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
        'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
        'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
        'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
        'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
        'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
        'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
        'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

    if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

before redirection you can check if it is mobile by using this code:

```
if(Mage::helper("CustomModule")->isMobile()){
    //Your mobile redirection code would be here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am running a Magento 1.9.4 store, so how to use it in M1?

Comment: This code is for M1